# How to deal with Makefile error: make: *** [Makefile:11: test] Error 3

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to build a Makefile for my code and for some reason I'm getting

> ./ex2_q1 11 24 36 7 5

> There were 3 prime numbers

> make: *** [Makefile:11: test] Error 3

The second line is the output of the program.
Everything seems to work Ok but I don't know why I'm getting the error.

the Makefile is:

```
PROG = ex2_q1

all: test

test: ex2_q1
    ./ex2_q1 11 24 36 7 5

factors.o: factors.c
    gcc -Wall -c factors.c

ex2_q1.o: ex2_q1.c
    gcc -Wall -c ex2_q1.c

clean: 
    rm -vf *.o $(PROG)
    rm -vf *.o factors
    rm -vf *.txt
    rm -vf *.log

factors: factors.o
    gcc -o factors -Wall factors.o

ex2_q1: ex2_q1.o factors
    gcc -o ex2_q1 -Wall ex2_q1.o
```

Comment: Most likely your program is exiting with a nonzero return code. What's in `ex2_q1.c`? I'd suggest adding `-Werror` to all your `gcc` lines in the Makefile, so that it will force you to fix any warnings (then do `make clean`); that may have helped prevent this issue.

Comment: The important diagnostic messages are earlier in `make`'s output.  You have omitted them, making it very difficult to determine what the problem is.

Comment: @JohnBollinger these are the messages I'm recieving:
gcc -Werror -Wall -c ex2_q1.c
gcc -Werror -Wall -c factors.c
gcc -Werror -o factors -Wall factors.
gcc -Werror -o ex2_q1 -Wall ex2_q1.o
./ex2_q1 11 24 36 7 5
There were 3 prime numbers
make: *** [Makefile:11: test] Error 3

Comment: @psmears Iv'e added that and still having no additional errors, like I quoted in the last comment.

Comment: @psmears Ok, I really was returning a nonzero return code. I fixed that and that seems to be it!

Comment: I am wondering about the whole structure of the Makefile. Why you write manually rules for every *.o file, why you create an executable ( factors ) and make ex2_q1 dependent from it but don't use it in the recipe.

Comment: Note: you can add a `-` at the beginning of the make recipe, and that will cause make to ignore the return value of the recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program, `ex2_q1` invoked as `./ex2_q1 11 24 36 7 5` returns a non-zero result.  This signifies an error and the proper way to address that is to fix your program.  If you cannot fix the program you can silence the error by changing the recipe to `./ex2_q1 11 24 36 7 5 || true`.  If you still want the error message but continue the build you can run make with `-k` flag, or you can prefix the recipe with a `-`:

```
test: ex2_q1
    - ./ex2_q1 11 24 36 7 5
```